# how to stack two columns

Tags: pandas, stack, pivot-table

I have a df as this:

```
                                 C  CF
NO FROMNODENO TONODENO                
1  1          2         582.551074   0
   2          1         809.018213   0
```

and I would like to obtain this:

```
                                   new value
NO FROMNODENO TONODENO new index            
1  1          2        C          582.551074
   2          1        C          809.018213
   1          2        CF           0.000000
   2          1        CF           0.000000
```

Note that there could be more columns at the beginning and some of them should not change. How to do it? And how to set the name of the new index the values of which come from the labels of the stack indices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html) for rename last level with [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html), for one column `DataFrame` use [`Series.to_frame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_frame.html):

```
df = df.rename_axis('new index', axis=1).stack().to_frame('new value')
print (df)
                                   new value
NO FROMNODENO TONODENO new index            
1  1          2        C          582.551074
                       CF           0.000000
   2          1        C          809.018213
                       CF           0.000000
```

Answer (score 1):

Can stack and unstack. Rename columns as may be appropriate

```
df.stack().unstack(level=0).rename(columns={1:'new value'}).reset_index()
```

Comment: thanks but I want to rename the new index, not the column

Comment: `df.stack().unstack(level=0).rename_axis('new index', axis=1).rename(columns={1:'new value'})`